# How to Handle String Encoding in JAVA(linux os)

Tags: java

I have one CSV file which contains many records. Noticed that some of the records contain French characters. My script reads each record and processes it and inserts the processed record in the XML. When we view the .csv file on terminal using VIM Editor on Fedora system, the French characters are displayed in correct format. But after processing the records these characters are not getting displayed properly. Also when such a record is printed on the console, it is not displayed properly.

For eg.

String in .csv file : Crêpe Skirt

String in XML : Cr�pe Skirt

code Snippet for Reading file.

BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileLocation));

String line = file.readLine();

Kindly suggest a way to handle such issue.

Comment: Please include your code for opening and reading the file.  It is probably as simple as specifying "UTF-8" encoding then reading the file.

Answer (score 2):

You need to know what encoding the file is in (probably UTF-8) and then when you open the file in Java specify the same encoding.

Answer (score 2):

try reading the file as UTF-8 file. And provide the encoding of your xml file as UTF-8 too

```
 BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(your-file-path),"UTF-8"));

    String line="";
    while((line=reader.readLine())!=null) {
        //Do your work here
    }
```